# Is there a special name for a norm that satisfies $||x+y|| \leq \max\{||x||, ||y||\}$?

Tags: analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

If we have a vector space $V$ with a norm $||\cdot ||$, is there a special name for it if it satisfies

$$||x+y|| \leq \max\{||x||, ||y||\} $$
for any $x,y \in V$? Im writing up something and I need a norm that satisfies this, but I cant recall if it has a special name.

Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrametric_space

Comment: @ZFR ahh yep, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called [ultrametric spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrametric_space).

(Posting a community-wiki answer so the question can be closed as answered.)